# is it necessary to rebuild react-native project after linking

Tags: react-native, react-native-linking

I would like to know if it's necessary to rebuild react native project after installing and linking libraries that includes native codes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as `react-native-link` updates some native files that are under the ios/android folder, that won't be checked during a reload/hot-reload/live-reload. All those files aren't checked in your jsBundle and are compiled during a `run-android` or `run-ios`.

Of course, if you added a new dependecy to the project and linked it, and you haven't used it anywhere in your code yet, you don't need it. If you are using that dependecy, your project instance will, most likely, die.

Answer (score 1):

if your react native version is below 0.60 then you have to run `react-native-link` after you install any react-native module. However after react-native version 0.60 and above, this is done automatically using the new "autolinking" feature added.

Read the changelog here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60

However you still need to rebuild your project after you install a native module but you dont need to run the `react-native-link` command anymore after installing every library after react-native@0.60 and above. Just type `react-native run-android`